# Toad Datapoint Export, Strange Behavior

Tags: export-to-excel, toad-data-point

I'm experiencing some strange behavior when I use the Quick Export - File function in Toad Datapoint, to export the result of a large sql Oracle query to Excel.  Using TOAD Datapoint 4.3 (I know it's not the latest version, but this is what my employer provides).

Has anyone else experienced this?

I see 2 background processes: Writing Data, and Exporting Data.  The Writing Data process completes pretty quickly and the progress bar advances.  But the Exporting Data process just sits there with no progress, sometimes for 30-45 minutes.  Then, for no particular reason that I'm aware of I get a message that the export is complete.  Even before that happens, I can see the exported file in Windows Explorer.

So basically 2 questions:
1) Why does this happen, and how can I make it stop?
2) Once the "Writing Data" process completes, is it OK to open the Excel, or will it somehow be incomplete or get corrupted if I don't wait for the Exporting Data process to complete?

Note, I usually just copy and paste from the results grid into Excel whenever possible, but for large data sets I sometimes have to use the Export function.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I still don't know why it happens, but I guess it's specific to my environment.

Anyway, I have a pretty good workaround.  Instead of exporting to excel, I export to CSV, then import the results into an excel workbook.  The "Writing Data" process completes immediately that way, and the whole thing is much faster.

Thanks for reading